# jackson serializer responding to metadata

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, jackson-databind

Is it possible to have jackson respond to metadata in other annotations somehow?

I want to do something like this:

```
public class Foo {

    UUID uuid;

    @Target("bar")
    @JsonSerialize(using = MySerializer.class)
    UUID barUUID;

}

public class Bar {

    UUID uuid;

    @Target("bar")
    @JsonSerialize(using = MySerializer.class)
    UUID fooUUID;

}
```

and then have it render the json like:

```
{
  "UUID": "50c3ef9f-9884-4cd8-8deb-647b30dfb35e",
  "fooUUID": "foo/50c3ef9f-9884-4cd8-8deb-647b30dfb35e"
}

{
  "UUID": "50c3ef9f-9884-4cd8-8deb-647b30dfb35e",
  "barUUID": "bar/50c3ef9f-9884-4cd8-8deb-647b30dfb35e"
}
```

but when i implement StdSerializer I just get this, and I can't figure out how to get to the contextual information form there....

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MySerializer extends StdSerializer<UUID> {
    protected MySerializer() {
        super(UUID.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(UUID value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {

    }
}
```

Comment: In the `Foo` class it should be `fooUUID` instead of `barUUID` ?

Comment: @dariosicily yesh - updated.